Is there we can ensure uniqueness in a non-key attribute for a given partition key in DynamoDB
Is there we can ensure uniqueness in a non-key attribute for a given partition key in DynamoDB.
For eg: We have person_id as the partition key and category#UUID as the sort key and we another attribute called category#effectiveDate. Now effectiveDate is mutable that is why we have not used this as sort key. But we also want to maintain ensure for a given person_id, category#effectiveDate remains unqiue. How can we do it?

There is only one way to achieve this and it's by using a second table and Transactions, where the category#UUID is a partition key on the second table.
Fully explained in this blog post.

Why can't query LSI on category#effectiveDate work in same transaction?

LSI does not maintain uniqueness.

No but I can query LSI made against category#effectiveDate before inserting in DB as I know partition key. Won't this work?

If you're building a single threaded application, then it might be ok.
